# Xcode 7.3.1: New project templates' screen's text is overlapped

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, macos-sierra

There are some overlapped fields while choosing template for new project. e.g. iOS -> Application -> Single View Application and I've also tried with Xcode 8, I didn't encounter any problem rather Xcode 7.3.1 @macOS Sierra.

[Screenshot: Choose options for your new project:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tm4u2.png)

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: How can I fix it? I tried reinstalling the Xcode but not solved.

Comment: Might be Xcode bug.

Comment: It looks like there might not be a fix. A comment on https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66184 says "I believe Xcode 8.x is recommended for use w/Sierra."