# Xcode option labels overlay text fields?

Tags: xcode

As of late, any time I use Xcode (7), the option labels overlay the text fields. A few days ago I wiped my computer and re-installed everything (for unrelated reasons), and Xcode is still behaving this way. Any thoughts? Here's the new project screen.
[image: Here's the new project screen.]

Comment: Does this happen in every view, even in a new project, or is it specific to one project, storybored, view, etc.?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712664/xcode-7-3-1-new-project-templates-screens-text-is-overlapped